# jquery ui resizable update image dimensions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jquery ui resizable to resize image and [this plugin to rotate it](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples)

Now when i rotate it let's say `90` degrees `resizable` doesn't know that i did that, so i need to somehow update it or maybe kill it and run it again? Either way i'm not so sure how to do it, could some one help me out with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can destroy / re-initialize it using:

```
$('.ui-resizable').resizable('destroy').resizable();
```

Here's an example - http://jsfiddle.net/U7Hqm/1/

Comment: Yeah thank you i figured that by myself, it doesn't help thou, since that plugin  is using `-webkit-transform: rotate()` and dimensios from what i can see stays the same, so i will probably gonna need to rotate it with php and reload the whole image, anyways thank you.